# Rails 3 Cache - Errno::ENOENT: No such file or directory

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, caching

Error:

```
Errno::ENOENT: No such file or directory - .../production/releases/20120224120523/tmp/cache/55B/D80/views%2Ffooter
```

View:

```
<% cache("footer") do %>
  <%= render :partial => "partials/footer" %>
<% end %>
```

Cache sweeper:

```
def after_create()
  expire_fragment("footer")
end
```

What could be wrong? My cache folder has chmod 744, and the file is actually there when I look.

**Edit:**

Here is the backtrace: http://pastie.org/4103699

Comment: What are you doing to get this error?

Comment: Oh sorry. I see this error in my error monitor (Airbreak). I see a couple of these every week. Is the backtrace interesting?

Comment: Yeah, you might want to post that as well.